# actionscript how can I get class name from array

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to print class name such as Insect,Insect2 from an array. but I don't do this. I am also try using insects[i].name. But the output will shown only object. But I want to show Insect,Insect2. How can I solve this.

```
 private var insects:Array;
    var ins:MovieClip;
    var ins:MovieClip;
                //trace(Math.random());
                if(Math.random()>0.5){
                    ins = new Insect();
                    ins.speedY = insectSpeed;
                    ins.score = -10;
                }else{
                    ins = new Insect2();
                    ins.speedY = insect2Speed;
                    ins.score = 1;
                }
                game_mc.addChild(ins);
                    insects.push(ins);
for(var i:int=0;i<insects.length;i++){

                trace(insects[i].name);
                    trace(insects[i]);

}
```

> Output---[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMjGX.png)

I want to print only **Insect or Insect2** name. How can I do that?

Comment: i had been given name . but  do not print Insect or Insect2.``` var ins:MovieClip;
   //trace(Math.random());
   if(Math.random()>0.5){
    ins = new Insect();
    ins.name='ins1';
    ins.speedY = insectSpeed;
    ins.score = -10;
   }else{
    ins = new Insect2();
    ins.name='ins2';
    ins.speedY = insect2Speed;
    ins.score = 1;
   }
   game_mc.addChild(ins);
   ins.y = -100;
   ins.x = Math.random()*640;
   insects.push(ins);```

Answer (score 1):

There's a method to obtain a class name from the object or class reference.

```
import flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName;

for (var i:int = 0; i < insects.length; i++)
{
    trace(getQualifiedClassName(insects[i]));
}
```